# Does pipelineing HTTP requests really result in faster page loads? Why?

Tags: http, tcp

A frequently cited argument is basically the one contained in this picture
 [image]

However, this does not reflect the reality of an underlying TCP connection which has to slowstart, and where the client acknoledges every other segment received from the server.  Whenever the client has something to send (e.g. an HTTP request) ACKs will be piggy-backed. So where's the gain here?

Comment: in the HTTP sense, this is not what I have understood pipelining to be. its not a traffic pattern, but the means by which a given request is directed to the module that is capable of processing it. http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture look at the section under "Native Modules". Otherwise on a TCP level, HTTP requests and responses are streams, and not entirely 1-to-1 with the packets sent. your diagrams appear to show requests and responses, not packets. TCP Windowing would be pertinent to the way you describe it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why pipelining is faster than pure persistent HTTP connections:

1. Multiple HTTP requests may be batched in a single TCP segment
2. Multiple HTTP replies (for small files) may be batched in a single (or fewer) TCP segment(s)
3. Slow start is actually rather fast, namely exponential. After *n* round-trip times, the batch size is already between *2^n* to *2^(n+1)* segments long. For *n*=10, this means 1024…2048 segments or (typically) 140…300 Kilobytes per RTT.
4. If the TCP connection is still open from a previous HTTP request (or set of requests), we are already out of the slow-start phase.

As pipelining is simple to implement for most systems, I would go for it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is in keeping the pipe full as much as possible, instead of letting it drain in between requests.

With pipelining, the server -> client direction of the pipe is constantly full, for max throughput and minimum latency.

Without pipelining, you've got a "stop and wait" protocol where the server -> client direction keeps going idle between the time the last frame of one response is sent, and before the first frame of the next response is sent. The pipe sits idle for the entire cumulative time it takes all of these things to happen:

1. The time it takes for the last frame of the first server response to transit the network.
2. The time it takes the client to act on receipt of that frame and prepare its new request.
3. The time it takes the new client request to transit the network.
4. The time it takes the server to prepare its response to the new request.